# MySql Remote server connection access denied

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have created a free application using [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), and created MySQL and phpmyadmin cartridges and inside my phpmyadmin I have gave access to all users from anywhere with all privileges now the problem is when I try to connect from my local MySQL workbench i get connected but I don't see my tables I have created in remote server using phpmyadmin and I can't do any action at all like creating schemas or tables where i get

> ERROR 1044: Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Remember that I allowed all privileges for any user, but I still get access denied for any action except only for the database connection.

Comment: Are you sure you added privileges for the user 'user' and not 'root'?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you've given full permissions to is the same user MySQL Workbench is connecting as -- there's a difference between the hosts `%` and `localhost` for instance. From MySQL Workbench, issue the "Status" command and compare the username and host against what you've configured.

You're apparently connecting through 'localhost' so you have to give full permissions to the anonymous user with host localhost (or change your connection type to tcp so that your connection is via 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost).

**Edit for further clarification:** The MySQL permission structure treats different types of connections differently; a client connecting via TCP connection always appears to come from an IP address, even if it's from the "local host" (in the sense of being on the same machine), in which case that IP address of the incoming connection may be 127.0.0.1. Socket type connections are registered in MySQL as coming from the host "localhost" (literally, in this case). This is why we're verifying which host MySQL Workbench is connecting as.

Different connection types appear differently to MYSQL even if they're coming from the same "local machine." Furthermore, the wildcard host does not include 'localhost' socket connections, those are a separate entry in the permissions field with the 'localhost' host name; the wildcard does not apply, as I explained above. This is the reason why we're checking which permissions you set against what MySQL Workbench is connecting as; it's the most common cause of difficulties such as these.

Comment: i think it's obvious that openshift free account does not allow remote sql access

Comment: as said i allowed permission for anyuser without any credentials, unless this worked with you on openshift?

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed where you said it was the free account, but that's really beside the point as the MySQL permission structure remains the same even when hosts block outside connections. It would be quite helpful if you could post either a screenshot or the SQL export of the permissions you've granted plus check the `STATUS` command from MySQL Workbench. See the information in the edit above for some more detailed explanation. I can't assure you this is the correct solution as I don't yet have enough information, but it seems most likely at this time :)